# Haskell - Returning a list of n lists that count frequencies of each character in string

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm currently trying to solve a little problem.

I want to create a function `occurrences` that is defined as such:

```
occurrences:: Int -> String -> [[(Char, Int)]]
```

The function accepts an Int and String as its parameters; where Int represents the number of occurrence lists to be printed. The number of occurrences for each character should be sorted in descending order.

For example, `occurrences 2 'hi'` should return `[[('h', 1), ('i', 1)], [('h', 1), ('i', 1)]]` and `occurrences  3 'foo'` would return `[[('o', 2), ('f', 1)], [('o', 2), ('f', 1)], [('o', 2), ('f', 1)]]`

So far I've added the below as part of my implementation for the occurrences function.

```
occurrences str = map (\x -> [(head x, length x)]) $ group $ sort str
```

But this just prints `[[('h',1)],[('i',1)]]` rather than `[[('h', 1), ('i', 1)]]` and I'm not sure how to return `n` number of lists according to the input as I'm new to Haskell.

Can I get help on this please?

Comment: Out of curiosity, it's one thing to know you can use the `replicate` function to replicate a list, but what purpose does it serve to have multiple copies of the same list in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `[[('h',1)],[('i',1)]]` to `[('h', 1), ('i', 1)]` using [`concat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat). Once you've done that, you'd want to [`replicate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) it the specified number of times.

Comment: I think rather than calling `concat`, they should probably just write `foo` instead of `[foo]` in their `map`.

Answer (score 0):

It works well.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord (comparing) 

occurrences n = replicate n . reverse . sortBy (comparing snd) . map (\x -> (head x, length x)) . group . sort
main = print $ occurrences 3 "aabaccaccbbcc"
```

output:

```
[[('c',6),('a',4),('b',3)],[('c',6),('a',4),('b',3)],[('c',6),('a',4),('b',3)]]
```